# Filter BlackDuck Project Names with hub-rest-api python

Tags: python-3.x, api, blackduck

I could able to set the limit to pull the project names like below from blackduck,

hub = HubInstance()
projects = hub.get_projects(limit=999)

Is there any way to filter the project names starting with particular string?

projects = hub.get_projects(limit=999, project_name="App1*") ?

Exception something like below

projects = hub.get_projects(limit=999, project_name="App1*")

Output has list of all projects starting with App1